# Прозрачный экран на Android эмуляторе

Tags: android, android-studio

начинал знакомиться с Android-studio. Создал пустой проект, но вместо окна приложения при запуске экран совершенно прозрачный. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зайдите в настройки эмулятора и у меню Graphics выставьте Software. [image: fix]